# Flash Builder / Flex: Making the auto-completion work like Flash Develop's (string patterns)

Tags: apache-flex, autocomplete, flash-builder, pattern-matching, flashdevelop

Is there some way to make the Auto-Completion of Flash Builder / Flex behave similarly, if not exactly the same, as Flash Develop's smart way of picking up the patterns in the var/method/property that you type?

For instance, currently Flash Builder and Flex requires you to type character-for-character the class name, property or method that you want to use:

```
/*
 still won't read your mind whether you're looking for URLRequest or URLLoader at
 this point, might even be an UncaughtError perhaps?
*/
var myURL:U... [???]
```

But the FlashDevelop way, you could type a portion and it would still make some sense of what you're attempting to complete and filters the auto-complete list to show only the most relevant items:

```
/*
 Hurray! Only had to type "UReq" and it automatically picks it up as we expected.
*/
var myURL:UReq...   [URLRequest]
var myURL2:Req...   [URLRequest, maybe some other classes...]
var myURL3:quest... [URLRequest, and maybe some other 'quest' matches...]
```

Is there any plugins available in Flash Builder, Flex or Eclipse to extend the Auto-Completion functionality this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, still a lot of features lacking in Flash Builder.  You might want to look at FDT or IntelliJ if you want another IDE.  Or you can also look at [SourceMate](http://www.elementriver.com/sourcemate3), a very good Flash Builder plugin to add the features you need that FB doesn't give you :)

Comment: mmmmmmmmmmmm.... I love what I'm seeing in SourceMate's website demo video! :D Thanks for this recommendation!